# Adding magento product from frontend with attributes

Tags: magento, addition, product

How to add product from frontend with custom attributes ?
I have this code form another stack question

```
//$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$product = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();
echo time();
// Build the product
$product->setAttributeSetId(9);// #4 is for default
$product->setTypeId('simple');

$product->setName('Some cool product name');
$product->setDescription('Full description here');
$product->setShortDescription('Short description here');
$product->setSku(time());
$product->setWeight(4.0000);
$product->setStatus(1);
$product->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);//4
print_r(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);

$product->setPrice(39.99);// # Set some price
$product->setTaxClassId(0);// # default tax class

$product->setStockData(array(
'is_in_stock' => 1,
'qty' => 99999
));

$product->setCategoryIds(array(27));// # some cat id's,

$product->setWebsiteIDs(array(1));// # Website id, 1 is default

//Default Magento attribute

$product->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now'));


//print_r($product);
try {
    $product->save();
    echo "Product Created";
}
catch (Exception $ex) {
    //Handle the error
    echo "Product Creation Failed";
}
```

But i have custom attributes also , and how to add them from that code.

Comment: Please give me custom attribute details...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each attribute you have you need to call:

```
$product->setData('attribute_code_here', 'Value here');
```

**[Edit]**

For yes/no attributes do it like this:

```
$product->setData('attribute_code_here', 1); //1 for Yes, 0 for No
```

For multiple selects

```
$product->setData('attribute_code_here', "4,6,12"); //the ids of the values concatenated by comma.
```

Comment: And how this works for example multiselect fields ? or yes/no

$product->setData('code', 'Yes'); - doesnt work

Comment: In Yes/No it is 1/0 values

Comment: @user3245106. See my update for yes/no and multiselects

Comment: Ok the values from multiselect fields have id - but where i can find that id ?

Only by selecting them all and pushing print_r ? In Admin Panel there are only values.

Comment: @user3245106. In the  backend if you use Firebug for FF or chrome, you can inspect the element for each value and you will see the name of the field like this `option[value][61][0]`, The `61` is the option id.

Answer (score 0):

First add a product with all attributes per hand into your Magento, so that you can figure out how Magento uses them. Load that Product and `print_r` all variables, then use them to save a new product.

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load('PRODUCT ID');

Zend_Debug::dump($_product);
```

Get All the Attributes you need to save a new Product and do that:

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$_product->setYourAttribute('...');
$_product->save();
```